# "Это — то, что их окружает..."

Tags: пунктуация

"Это — то, что их окружает, то, что создается их руками" — правильно ли тут поставлено тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом предложении допустимо тире, так как после слова ЭТО может быть длительная пауза. В Вашем предложении ЭТО будет подлежащим, ТО - сказуемым в главном предложении "Это - то..." СР.: Это есть то, что их окружает. Но если паузы нет, то тире не ставится. Всё зависит от авторского замысла и авторской интонации.

Comment: Ставится тире или нет - все равно ЭТО - подлежащее, ТО - сказуемое.

Comment: Да, бесспорно. Я  не совсем точно выразилась. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как объянить, но тире здесь не надо))

Answer (score 0):

после местоимения тире не ставится, как в "это учитель"